# Reverse PCIe bifurcation possible (two x4 into one x8)?

Tags: pcie

I'm just curious if this is possible in real world applications and if it is, what is it called? Reverse PCIe bifurcation?

Context: We know an example of PCIe bifurcation is converting an x8 into two x4s. Is there a possibility to convert two x4s from different CPUs into one x8?

The application would be to share an x8 PCIe NIC with two CPUs that only have a max. of one x4 lanes each. Since I can't find any materials or resources online regarding this, and from the feedbacks, I would say this is nearly impossible.

[image]

Comment: it seems hard to do right, but I cannot think of a reason why this cannot be done.

Comment: What behavior do you expect from the device when the 2 CPUs are stuck together like that? Are the 2 CPUs supposed to be synchronized together somehow? How? I can't see any way to make this setup useful, even if it were possible.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. To me, this question is purely an idea and not a practical requirement for an electronics design application. Voting to close for that reason, I'm afraid. I recommend you edit the question (not post info in comments) and add detail that explains what application would require this. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so the question and any answers must have discernible value for future readers. Thanks.

Comment: Having one device on two different PCIe links has nothing to do with the reverse of bifurcation (aggregation), so essentially you're asking a different question. What you're asking about is merely having two PCIe links, which many devices can do (chipsets, PCIe switches, FPGAs, etc). An existing NIC chip most likely won't support this because it's an unusual thing for a NIC, but nothing stops you from designing one that did if for some reason you had a use for it.

Answer (score 2):

The reverse of bifurcation is 'aggregation'. It could be possible using a bridge, but I doubt it.

PCIe isn't designed to do that. Instead, sets of PCIe lanes have a specific, byte-by-byte allocation of data across lanes it establishes with a link partner. The data payload is point-to-point and isn't 'channelized' at that level (like MIPI or DisplayPort for example.) It's just one payload. Within that link, the amount of allowed inter-lane skew (delay) is very small, on the order of 2 bit (UI) times. This skew cannot be ensured if the lanes are bifurcated.

Any such aggregation would have to be at a layer above PCIe. For example, two Ethernet controllers were each attached to two four-lane ports, you could double your throughput. This is because Ethernet allows multiple links, and with the appropriate protocol, can tolerate out-of-order packet arrivals. This isn't dealt with at the link or MAC level, it's higher layers of the protocol (specifically, TCP) deals with packet reordering.

If your PCIe system is a CPU or other root complex that is capable of bifurcation, it's also possible that your root can also support re-allocating the x4 ports into one x8. For a CPU, check with the motherboard vendor to see if they support the x8 mode as well as the popular x4 mode (they usually do.)

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Do you think aggregation is possible if two x4 lanes are coming from two different CPUs?

Comment: I think it's unlikely.

Comment: It will not just be unlikely, it will not be possible. The only feasible thing is that a single PCIe root port port from the CPU is brought out as a wide bus it is possible to split it out into various bifurcations. The full capabilities for bifurcations for from a single PCIe root port will depend upon the specific capabilities of that port. For example a x16 bus may also operate as two x8 ports or even four x4 ports. x2 and x1 bus widths are also possible in some cases. Do think about your two CPU idea and realize that that would involve two different PCIe root ports and thus not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be possible, anyway the way that you have drawn the diagram. It wouldn't make sense to connect a PCI device to two separate CPUs because the data handling and interrupts wouldn't work.

Comment: That topology is possible, it is used for CXL devices, which run on top of PCIe as the physical layer and can connect multiple CPUs to a single devic. Logically I think these devices are actually several PCIe devices on a common chip with the CXL stack routing between them, but I'm not super familiar with the internal details.

Comment: In mult CPUs they usually connect to a bridge and that handles the PCI bus, but it's my understanding that only one CPU can talk at one time

Comment: They'd be connected with a CXL switch, which is essentially the box he drew with a bunch of different PCIe links between two (or more) CPUs. He's really asking about this CXL-like topology where devices are shared between CPUs.